# Find basis and dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have finite dimensional vector space F and subspace V, such that for its vector of subspace, sum of coordinates of a vector equals zero.

How do I find basis and dimension of this subspace?

Comment: $(1,-1,0,0,0,\dots),(1,0,-1,0,0,\dots),(1,0,0,-1,0,\dots),\dots$

Comment: Note that this is a special case of the problem of finding the basis of the nullspace of a matrix, for which you might know a general algorithm.  The matrix is $[1, 1, 1, \dots, 1]$. Any general algorithm you know for $m \times n$ matrices will also for $1 \times n$ matrices.

Comment: There may be some missing information about a basis for the "ambient" vector space $F$.  If $F$ is finite dimensional, then it has a finite basis. If $F$ is given in terms of coordinates (drawn from its scalar field), then you can apply either of the two Comments above to modify a standard basis for $F$ into a smaller basis for $V$, though if the scalar field is of characteristic prime $p\gt 0$, there is a possible technical problem with the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $v=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in V$ where $n=\dim F$. Thus, $x_n=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i$ and $x_1,...,x_{n-1}$ are free. This means that the dimension is $n-1$ and to find a base you can put $x_i=1$, $x_j=0$ if $i\neq j<n$ and $x_n=-1$.